Issue with Kmeans in Python
I am analysing some neural data, and want to use Kmeans to cluster the true spikes of the neuron, and the noise into two separate clusters. I have here a test array of the candidate data I want to give K means.
Here is my code:
import pickle
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

fileName = 'test_array.pickle'

with open(fileName, 'rb') as file:
    output = pickle.load(file)
    print('Decomposition successful')

    # Initialize KMeans with 2 clusters (spikes and noise)
    kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=2, init='k-means++', n_init=1, verbose=1)
    kmeans.fit(output.reshape(-1,1))
    print('K means works')

But, when I apply Kmeans, it seems to not run through it. It is not throwing any specific error, but does give this warning: Intel MKL WARNING: Support of Intel(R) Streaming SIMD Extensions 4.2 (Intel(R) SSE4.2) enabled only processors has been deprecated. Intel oneAPI Math Kernel Library 2025.0 will require Intel(R) Advanced Vector Extensions (Intel(R) AVX) instructions.
I have am M1 Macbook Pro (which I have read leads to this warning being thrown sometimes...), but other than this I'm not sure specifically what is wrong, I would appreciate some help and advice! Thanks in advance, here is a test code, and a link to the pickle test array
https://drive.google.com/file/d/19USY6Sl07Cw4zU0qIUvdOjQIq748OIHf/view?usp=sharing
Adding error statements e.g. value, memory errors

you just get a deprecation warning, don't worry about it.  What is your question?  You say that " it seems to not run through it."  What is the output of the classifier ? What makes you think it doesn't work?

Okay thanks, good to know about the depreciation warning :) I don't end up with an output, because it is as though it never finishes the Kmeans, not sure why because I think just looking at the data it should be able to be split into two clusters

but you never look at the data. you save the kmeans result in the variable kmeans, then you print print('K means works') and then your program finishes. Once the program finishes, all information from variables is lost.

But for me it doesn't end up printing this print line, so it makes me think that the Kmeans hasn't completed, it doesn't give the kmeans variable in my debugger output

please could you include the outputs you see in the console when running the program? you can try running it with verbose=1 to see more information when the Kmeans is running. You should also edit your question so your code is properly formatted

Sure! So I changed the lines to:    kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters = 2, init = 'k-means++',n_init = 1, verbose=1) # two classes: 1) spikes 2) noise
kmeans.fit(output.reshape(-1,1)). And then the only printed output is 'Initialisation is complete'. I will change the question formatting too!

don't post a comment with what you changed. Post it in the question.

have done now, sorry!

cannot reproduce. It works for me and finishes under a second. Could it be that if you are debugging you have a breaking point that interrupts the execution?  Try running the code from the console and check if it works.
